# Which is bigger? $\sum_1^n$ or $\int_1^n$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

I was shocked to see that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac {\pi^2}{6}$ is greater than $\int_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} = 1$. I always thought that integration over $[1, \infty]$ will always be greater than the sum of the series for the same function over all natural numbers.
So, really my question is how $\sum$ could possibly be greater than $\int$ ?

Comment: Draw a picture to see what's going on.

Comment: Have a look at the graph here ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant

Comment: Check out the Euler-Maclaurin formula for the difference between sums and integrals.

Comment: @RobertShore Yeah it's easy to see. I was picturing the values of sum in a completely wrong way. When I noticed that each value in summation will have a width of 1,it's easy to see why a decreasing function's summation will be larger than the integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is a *decreasing* function, then draw a graph and you'll see that we have

$$\int_1^n f(x) \, dx \le \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f(i)$$

for all positive integers $n$ (consider the left Riemann sum - you'll end up drawing a bunch of rectangles). If $f$ is increasing then the left Riemann sum is a lower bound rather than an upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{n^2} dx \ge \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{x^2} dx = \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}dx
$$

The key step is to realize that, since $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is decreasing in the interval $[n, n+1]$, we have that in that interval $\frac{1}{n^2}\ge \frac{1}{x^2}$. Using the same argument, we cal also say that
$$
\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}dx \ge \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}. 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Integration and summation are fundamentally different, although you could define them with a Lebesgue integral with respect to different measures. In this case, the summation is an approximation of the integral called a Riemann sum. Regardless, you can formalize your example using the floor function

\begin{align*}
&\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} dx\\
&<\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor^2} dx\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor^2} dx\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{n^2} dx\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to show the complete picture of the integral and the sum.
For any $k<x<k+1$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{k^2} &>\frac{1}{x^2}>\frac{1}{(k+1)} \\
\int_k^{k+1} \frac{1}{k^2} d x&>\int_k^{k+1} \frac{1}{x^2} d x>\int_k^{k+1} \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} d x \\
\frac{1}{k^2} &>\int_k^{k+1} \frac{1}{x^2} d x>\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Summing them up from $k=1$ to $\infty$ gives the required inequalities as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}&>\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_k^{k+1} \frac{1}{x^2} d x>\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\\
&\frac{\pi^2}{6}>\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} d x>\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps!